# SFMC RMM: Using AmpScript in User Specified Information

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, reply-mail-management

The Sendable DE I am using to send emails has fields *ReplyToName* and *ReplyToEmailAddress* to which a reply to that email should go to. These two data elements may be different for each email sent.

I set up RMM as follows:
Checked box
**Use Custom setting below**

In the **Forward to**: section selected the second radio button

**Use specified information**

**Name:** `%%ReplyToName%%`

**Address**: `%%ReplyToEmailAddress%%`

In a test I replied to the email I sent myself using Postman. The email address in `*ReplyToEmailAddress*` never received the reply.

Is AmpScript substitution allowed in these fields?
If not does someone have a suggested solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this myself. I am posting a simplified answer here. In reality I am also checking for blank/null values and substituting default values etc.

Add the following AmpScript in the **Name** and **Address** fields under the **Specified Information** section

Name: `%%[SET @FromName = AttributeValue("ReplyToName")]%% %%=v(@FromName)=%%`

Address: `%%[SET @ReplyToEmail = AttributeValue("ReplyToEmailAddress")]%% %%=v(@ReplyToEmail)=%%`

ReplyToName and ReplyToEmailAddress are fields on the Trigger Send DE record.